# How to create something similar to groups or user permission selection options in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am new in modifying the Django admin panel. I am trying to create something similar to the default user permission selection option in the Django admin panel.
[image]

I want to list all the records from a model and need to assign the foreign key of selected options to another model.

Is there any way to create something similar to this.

Thanks.

Try to find a tutorial which is trying to creating similar functionality, but till now not able to find anything on google and not in the django's documentations.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292574/django-filter-multi-select-list-in-admin